# Pip install not working in docker containers on window

Tags: python-3.x, docker, window, containers, dockerfile

I am using docker on window.
Below is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install flask
CMD ["cmd"]
```

When I try to build docker image it throws the folowing exception:

```
>docker build  D:\HCL\Docker\

Sending build context to Docker daemon  14.34kB
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:latest
 ---> ea9f7aa13d03
Step 2/4 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> 2137b5b81384
Step 3/4 : RUN pip install flask
 ---> Running in 7463787fcfa8

Collecting flask

  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; pip install flask' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

- I have checked docker has internet access but not able to download any package over https.
- I have checked downloading files over http and it is working fine.
- I am able to install windowcore and python in the same docker file.
- I am only getting issue with pip.
- I have logged into the container and run the pip command manualy but got the same error.

Comment: try `python -m pip install flask`

Comment: Thanks Mayur, but i am getting same error  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/flask/

Comment: I think you have slow internet connection try this, `python -m pip --default-timeout=1000 install flask`

Comment: I am working on gcp VM so there is no any issue with internet.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find a solution?  I am not behind a proxy, and have no trouble installing packages on my windows dev machine.  But impossible to get them installed in Windows Docker container

Comment: Hey @S kumar any updates about this question? got the same problem here...the only difference is that I am trying to run it from my wifi and not connected to any cloud